# Want to use single web socket for entire REACT app but socket gets created on every navigations

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-router

I am a novice on REACT and have one issue on web-socket. I would like to open a socket when a client is connected and I would like to let the client to use the socket as long as client is on our website.

So, I would like to have a singleton socket instance. How do we do this?
Following code shows my attempt.

```
const socket = io(
  process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
);

console.log("This is printed on every navigations");

function App() {
  console.log("This one, too.");

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <SocketProvider socket={socket}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <ScrollToTop>
            <Switch>
              <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route path='/' component={Main} />
            </Switch>    
          </ScrollToTop>  
        </BrowserRouter>
      </SocketProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, new socket is connected on every navigation.
eg.
http://localhost:3000          // Socket created.
http://localhost:3000/login    // Socket created again.

I thought above code would work because socket is created outside of BrowserRouter component. I think I am missing a detail on how REACT works.

Much appreciate for reading this.
Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

ah, I just noticed that I was navigating with `<a>` tag.

https://markadamfoster.com/react-anchor-tags-vs-link-components/

It says,

`If linking to a different URL within your app, use the <Link> component. This will (depending on the routing library you’re using) still ultimately render a semantically valid a tag, but doesn’t refresh the page and gives you additional prop options that can be super handy (check your routing library’s docs for details).`

`<a>` tag induces a refresh and socket was created again.
With `<Link>`, no issue.